# In Python, what would be the shortest code to make a list from another list and display it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the shortest way to achieve the following?

Take a list, say for example this one:

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
```

Then, make a new list that has all the elements less than 5 from this list in it and print out this new list.

```
b = []
for value in a:
    if value < 5:
        b.append(value)
for value in b:
    print(value)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [List Comprehensions](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python):

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]

b = [i for i in a if i < 5]

print b
[1, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`filter`](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#filter) function.

```
b = filter(lambda x: x < 5, a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
b = [x for x in a if x < 5]
```